# Resources that explain Linux source code

Tags: linux, resources

Looking for resources that can help getting 'into' the Linux code. Could not get much help on Google. I have no issues  on the distro covered by the book/resource, but will like if Fedora is the base. Also, it would be great if the resource is well maintained and updated.

Comment: http://www.spinellis.gr/codereading/

Comment: Understanding the Linux Kernel:
http://www.makelinux.net/books/ulk3/

Comment: Linux Kernel Development:
http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this looks promising:

http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHacking

Note that you will need to be familiar with Operating Systems concepts to even understand the concepts of how memory is allocated, how processes are scheduled, and whatnot.  Also, the code of the linux kernel is monstrously complex.

You are undertaking a daunting task.  But have fun with it.  You might want to start with a small device driver's code.

Comment: Taken a standard course in OS. And that probably is the motivation to get into these things. By the way, any idea about Tanenbaum's OS Design and Implementation. In that he supposedly develops Minix from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.makelinux.net/kernel_map may be a good place to start. A clickable map which takes you to the part of the source you clicked. Readable in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Linux kernel, [kernel newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) is absolutely awesome. Besides that, I don't think theres a single resource to recommend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to understand the linux kernel source code, then the exact distribution you are using, is not very relevant.

I would recommend the book from Robert Love: [Linux Kernel Development](http://blog.rlove.org/2010/07/linux-kernel-development-third-edition.html), currently in its third edition. It will give you an understanding of the main parts of the kernel.